# How can I update the column rather then adding another value to it?

Tags: php, mysql

So I've created a form on my website, it has one input and when the user fills it it store it in the datebase table, it stores what user wrote.

Now whenever I again type something it adds just one more value to the column and I want to replace the one that is already added. So what I want is when I type for example "Datebase" it will be stored in the MySQL table, but again when I type "Datebase change" in the same input it will just the update the current value and it will be changed from "Datebase" to "Datebase change". So I dont want to add more values I just need this one input which will change what it is on column on every submit.

My code:

```
<?php 

$title = 'Admin Panel - Edit';
include '../config.php';

$heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['heading']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO content (heading) VALUES ('$heading')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

?>

<form action="edit.php">
    <input type="text" name="heading" id="heading" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You need UPDATE for that. That or REPLACE.

Comment: can you help me with my code?

Comment: You've been given an answer by another member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` adds a new row to the table.  `UPDATE` updates existing rows.  So you might do something like this:

```
UPDATE content SET heading = ?
```

(Note: I'm using a parameter placeholder here.  While escaping input the way you currently do is a good idea, it's not the correct approach.  Query parameters are still safer and more stable in general.  [This is a good place to start for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php))

**Note however** that, without a `WHERE` clause, this will replace *every* record in the table.  Though it *sounds like* you only ever want there to be one record in the table and so this is your actual desired behavior, is that correct?  If so then I suppose a simple approach in terms of logical steps might be:

- Read from the table.
- If a row exists, update.
- Else, insert.

But this ends up querying the database twice, when with the right data model you only need to do it once.  If your table has a simple `int` primary key, *not* auto-increment, then you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO content (id, heading) VALUES(1, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE heading = ?
```

What this would do is explicitly insert a hard-coded primary key of `1`.  Or, if that key already exists in the table (meaning you've already inserted your one intended record) then it updates that record.